# Get woocomerce SKU in ACF relationship field result

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, relationship, advanced-custom-fields

i am trying to have the woocomerce sku to display in the relationship box that i have created using ACF.

Now Eliot has a tutorial in the following link: 
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-result/

However i am kind of new to all that and whatever i try i get "null" result.

The goal is to get the SKU before the title (or the SKU only) so we can search for a product by its sku.

**The original code by Eliot:**

```
function my_relationship_result( $title, $post, $field, $post_id ) {

// load a custom field from this $object and show it in the $result
$page_views = get_field('page_views', $post->ID);


// append to title
$title .= ' [' . $page_views .  ']';


// return
return $result;

}



// filter for every field
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/result', 'my_relationship_result', 10, 4);
```

**The one i am trying to use:**

```
function my_relationship_result( $title, $post, $field, $post_id ) {

// load a custom field from this $object and show it in the $result
$sku = get_field('sku', $post->ID);


// append to title
$title .= ' [' . $sku .  ']';


// return
return $result;

}



// filter for every field
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/result', 'my_relationship_result', 10, 4);
```

Anyone can help me with that?

**Update:**
Elliot was pointing me to that maybe i need to use the relationship field query filter to modify the args during the search:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-query/

It is most likely that WC saves the SKU within the postmen table (custom field data), so we can use the custom field meta_query args to search.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sku = get_field('sku', $post->ID);

replace

$sku = get_field('_sku', $post->ID);
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: Dear @ShameOnU , I'm trying to add the following (with your change) to my functions.php but still getting "null", is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$result` variable doens't exists, just change the `return $result` to `return $title`